# Sorting in Tableview

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios

I am new to xamarin.ios wants to sort tableview in alphabetical order.ie every alphabet should display all the books starting with respective letter.I am able to list the details in tableview..need to sort and update cells

```
public class BooklistTableSourceClass : UITableViewSource
{
    public List<Booklist> Bookdata { get; set; }
   BooklistViewController parentcontroller;

    NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString("BooklistCell");

    public BooklistTableSourceClass(List<Booklist> listdata,BooklistViewController callingcontroller)
    {

        this.Bookdata = listdata;
        this.parentcontroller = callingcontroller;
    }



    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return Bookdata.Count;
    }


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {


                var cell = (BooklistCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Bcell_id", indexPath);



                var Bookitem = Bookdata[indexPath.Row];



                cell.UpdateCell(Bookitem);

                return cell;
    }


}
```

Output:
A->section header
1)A1  //book name
2)A2
3)A3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) in LINQ?

Sort the Bookdata first and then pass it as source of tableView instead of `UpdateCell` in `GetCell`.

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {

        public List<Booklist> Bookdata { get; set; }

        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            Bookdata = new List<Booklist>();
            Bookdata.Add(new Booklist("A2"));
            Bookdata.Add(new Booklist("A3"));
            Bookdata.Add(new Booklist("A1"));
            Bookdata.Add(new Booklist("122"));
            Bookdata.Add(new Booklist("C2"));
            Bookdata.Add(new Booklist("b2"));

            List<Booklist> sortedList = Bookdata.OrderBy(r => r.name).ToList();

            //pass the sortedList as source of tableview
            //...
        }
    }

    public class Booklist
    {
        public Booklist(string n){
            name = n;
        }

        public string name;
    }
```

If you want the  `A->section header`, I think there is another list that hold the header data. Or you can pick the first letter of data shows in each section as text shows in section header.